# Is it possible do multiple proptype type checks in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

This is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
const Component = ({data}) => null

const arrayShouldContainTwoItems = (props, propName, componentName) => {
// custom propCheck 
}

// perform 2 checks on the same prop
Component.propTypes = {
  data: React.PropTypes.array(PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object)) && 
  arrayShouldContainTwoItems
}
```

I noticed that it does validation of the second custom validator when using && and validation of the first validator when using ||, but not both.

Is there a way to add more that one validation schema the proptypes check in reactjs using [`prop-types`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types)?

Comment: PropTypes check for me is more like type checking and not validation. Maybe you can do the validation inside the component itself? Since that's where the actual "logic" should be in this instance

Comment: i actually meant type checking. thanks

Comment: I don't think so, you can check everything directly in your custom validation function

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for oneOfType:

```
myProp: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.number]),
```

Check it being used there: https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#proptypes

Comment: this seems like it's validating whether prop meets any of the conditions specified, how to look though if it is meeting all of the conditions?

Comment: You'd probably have to create your own prop validation function. What's your scenario? Can you provide an example?